# How can I set a placeholder value for my picker?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have this definition for my picker:

```
this.StateField = new UIDropdown<string>()
            {
                BackgroundColor = CoreTheme.COLOR_DEFAULT_INPUT_FIELD_BACKGROUND,
                PlaceholderText = "State",
                Data = new string[] { "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI", 
                    "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", 
                    "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", 
                    "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" },
                TextColor = CoreTheme.COLOR_DEFAULT_INPUT_FIELD_FOREGROUND,
                PlaceholderTextColor = CoreTheme.COLOR_DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT
            };
```

Where in my view I set it like this:

```
pickerkState = new UIPicker<string>(FieldDefinitions.StateField)
            {
                HeightRequest= DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultheight * 0.05
            };;
pickerState.Title = currentVM.State;
pickerState.SelectedIndex = 0;
pickerState.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                pkState.Title = pkState.Items[pkState.SelectedIndex];
                txtPostalCode.Focus();
            };
```

However, the placeholder value is not set and it shows the first element in the array as a placeholder value instead. How can I show a placeholder value for a picker?

I'm trying to do this in Xamarin.Forms particularly for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe UIPicker has a field for place holder text so

```
List<Model_State> states = new List<Model_State>();

Model_State unselected = new Model_State();
unselected.id = Enum_State.Unselected;
unselected.name = "Select State";

states.add(unselected);

Model_State AL = new Model_State();
AL.id = Enum_State.Alabama;
AL.name = "Alabama";

states.add(AL)
```

....add 49 more states

Comment: What if I wanted to add a placeholder for a DatePicker?

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about setting a date picker to something like ... "Select Date"? I do not have an answer for that. I generally just set the date picker to Now. You could do other things like put a button on the screen that sais Select Date then display a date picker upon click and feed the selection back into the buttons .Text.